# Можно ли через phpdoc описать тип переменной определенной в другом файле, чтобы включить автодополнение в NetBeans?

Tags: php, netbeans, phpdoc

Есть файл, содержащий в себе некоторую логику. Код написан в "глобальном стиле", то есть просто inlude'ом включается в нужном месте в другом файле. Внутри используется объект`$DB` для работы с БД. Во включаемом файле переменная `$DB` не определяется NetBeans'ом как объект типа `DBProvider` (ее инициализация во внешнем файле) и он не подсказывает методы объекта. 
Вопрос - можно ли при помощи phpdoc как то решить проблему? 
Пробовал что-то вроде

```
/**
*@global DBProvider @name $DB
*/
```

Но не то. Может кто знает как надо?

Comment: Указывать полное имя класса (вместе с неймспейсом) пробовали?

Comment: @var DBProvider $DB не?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за ответы и комментарии - вы подсказали мне правильное направление поиска. На английском SO есть [подобный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798477/variable-type-hinting-in-netbeans-php)

Суть в том, что хотя по правилам phpdoc писать надо так

```
/** @var objectType $varName */
```

Но в NetBeans (да в Eclipse/Zend Studio, как там пишут) это не сработает.

Писать надо вот так (порядок изменен - сначала имя, потом тип; одна строка, нет дополнительной * в начале)

```
/* @var $varName Type_Name */
```

И не иначе. Такой вариант `/** @var $varName Type_Name */` уже не сработает.

В моем случае просто `/* @var $DB DBProvider */` поставил в начале файла и NetBeans сразу распознал тип и начал подсказывать (при первом использовании переменной он ей имя дополняя не говорит еще какого она типа, но методы потом подсказывает, а при последующих использованиях уже и тип называет).

Answer (score 1):

Вот так:

```
/** @var DBProvider $DB **/
$DB....
```